# I can't select element backgroundColor in for statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, background-color

How can I to delete div image and select the div.backgroundColor :)

```
for (let i = 0; i < color1.length; i++) {
    color1[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {  
        color1[i].style.backgroundImage = "none";
        let colorItem = color1[i].style.backgroundColor;
        console.log(some)

        if (colorItem == "red") {
            console.log("yes")
        }
        else {
            console.log("no")
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does the element has the `style` attribute set with `backgroundColor` defined inline? Otherwise you need to use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: Yea the element have a background-color : red  but this event listener cant see this attribute. I was something try, but I can't do this. if loop always console.log("yes) result.

Comment: But is that defined as an inline style (i.e. in the `style="..."` attribute), or in the `<style>` tag? Your way of accessing it can only detect inline style, and not computed style.

Comment: Thank you very much. Resolved the issue with window.getComputedStyle.